Knex not compiling Date to ISO string
I am using knex.js with a postgresql database.
I am looking into replacing moment.js with date-fns in my codebase and I am running into a really odd situation with the formatting of queries.
We are using whereBetween with two dates. To test the transition from moment to date-fns (that use regular JS Date) I am building a query where the lower bound is a Date and the upper bound is a moment object.
When I try to toString() it I get two different formats:
select * from "table" where column between '2017-10-23 02:00:00.000' and "2017-10-23T23:59:59.999Z"
The first one is what I would consider wrong since it is in my timezone as well as not being an ISO string. This one is generated from the date. The other one is generated from a moment object which toString() would return Mon Oct 23 2017 23:59:59 GMT+0000 but it seems like it is using the toISOString() that returns the right format: 2017-10-23T23:59:59.999Z
I can't find the information on how the transformation is carried out and why this isssue arises. Has anyone dealt with this issue ?

It's not wrong. It's a local time. What's really wrong is "2017-10-23T23:59:59.999Z". The double quotes mean this is an object name, eg a column or table name. How was this string created? Post the actual code. I suspect the error is that instead of passing a Date value as a parameter, a serialized string was passed instead

Whether the offset even matters depends on the column type. PostgreSQL has no offset-aware date type. timestamp with timezone isn't really timezone-aware. The value is stored as UTC only and converted to the current timezone setting when reading. The original timezone is lost. To get a value in a different timezone you'd need to add AT TIME ZONE
